# Flash IC/ CMOS RAM/ microSD in TFT LCD

Tags: lcd, flash, tft

I have seen cases where TFT module contains flash or SD card on module. What is the need of flash in LCD?

In simplest way, we connect RS,RD/WR,CS,RESET pins and 7/8/16/24 bits data pins of controller to LCD. So, why this memory provision is there on board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images take up a lot of space. Putting them in some kind of external storage allows you to use a system controller with less program memory since you're not wasting this valuable space on images. Additionally, the images can be easily changed without any need to recompile.

Comment: In addition, such displays typically have their own microcontroller on board with graphics code burned into flash. This simplifies the coding on your processor. If you want to draw a circle, you would send a command with the center, radius, color, etc. instead of having to compute which pixels make up the circle and set them directly.